# docker local host url not opening

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, docker-machine

I installed docker and with tensorflow image I am unable to open in browser with jupyter notebook.
What am I missing??

command used:  **docker run -it -v /home/$USER_NAME/tf_files:/tf_files  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow**
where "gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow"  is the tensorflow image and "/home/surya" is $HOME.

[in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKpIz.png)

[output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvlbx.png)

PS: docker installation is correct as "docker run hello-world" gives required message.

Comment: You are not exposing any ports, therefore your machine can't access any services provided by your container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed to bind some ports. The official documentation of tensorflow provides the exposed ports with this command:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v /home/surya/tf_files:/tf_files gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

where `-p 8888:8888` means: link the port 8888 of my local machine with the service in the container, which is also 8888. Then you can access the service at http://localhost:8888

#### Why do I have to map a port?

Your container shows the following:

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=1b3ec72ff1ed67f77a09beaee1dc4b9ad4e7aee26401b6f0
```

which means that you have to connect to the running process inside the container with the port 8888. To make the port of the container accessible from your local machine, you have to add `-p 8888:8888` to your command. Then accessing the URL given to you from your container makes it possible to access the container's notebook via your local browser.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#2

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood you and only focused on accessibility in your browser

Comment: I have also checked the port 8888, it is not being used by any process.

Comment: Okay, still you have to add the port to your command line. I'll update my answer

Comment: ok got it. The mistake I did was "ordering of flags." I put -p 8888:8888 in the end which gave me error.

Comment: whenever I use "docker run -it <docker image>", it always put me in jupyter notebook in place of docker prompt. What should I do?

Comment: So you want a bash inside of your container? You can do this by connecting to a **running** container with `docker exec -it c6e2a4a64ef1 bash` whereas the hash beginning with `c6e` is your container id (see `docker ps`). **Or** you create a new container directly with a bash instead of the notebook: `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v $HOME/tf_files:/tf_files gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow bash` (append `bash` to your command)